# Correct use of all manner

Tags: word-usage, indefinite-article

I'm just looking at settling a debate of the correct use of *an all manner*.

> He looked around and saw an all manner of contraptions nailed to the wall.

> He looked around and saw all manner of contraptions nailed to the wall.

Is *an* before *all manner* grammatically correct? Does it make sense as a sentence?

Answer (score 1):

> He looked around and saw an all manner of contraptions nailed to the wall.

This particular usage doesn't make sense.

A possible way of using it in a similar way—although not one I've ever actually seen—would be as a compound adjective:

> He looked around and saw an all-manner contraption nailed to the wall.

This *might* "work" (or at least be understood) in the same sense that *an all-purpose contraption* works.

However, **all manner of** is actually an idiom, and would not normally be used differently than in its usual way as defined by Merriam-Webster:

> : all kinds or sorts of (things or people) • The store sells *all manner of* musical instruments. • *All manner of* people come to the city.